# What is the missing 'sqlite3.lib' file when trying to run rustqlite with precompiled binary on Windows 11?

Tags: database, sqlite, rust, linker

I'm new to the rust ecosystem bare in mind. I'm trying to use rustqlite crate so I can store really large indexes that don't fit into memory. I get an immediate **RUNTIME ERROR** where it faults and says:

```
= note: LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'sqlite3.lib'

linking with `link.exe` failed: exit code: 1181
```

I'm using the precompiled binary for sqlite3 windowsx86 and I only have a "tokens.db" along with my sqlite3.exe. What is the sqlite3.lib supposed to be? I've found no informative videos or searching and I've even installed brand new MS build tools and etc.

The rust code itself has no compiler errors and seems to look okay. I look forward to any insight on how to fix this

Comment: Do you have the `bundled` feature enabled?

Comment: @pigeonhands what is that? can you get into detail a bit

Comment: Its in the [readme for `rusqlite`](https://github.com/rusqlite/rusqlite). You need to use `rusqlite = { version = "0.29.0", features = ["bundled"] }` to not depend on the system's sqlite library.

Answer (score 5):

Simple fix in the `cargo.toml` as @pigeonhands pointed out. All I had to do was specify the features bundled option in the `rustqlite` dependency.

```
rusqlite = { version = "0.29.0", features = ["bundled"] }
```

Getting super slow writes to my DB but other than that works now thanks.

Comment: Are you compiling with optimizations?

Answer (score 2):

`sqlite3.lib` is a static library.

*The following works with `diesel` for the same error, I assume it also works for `rusqlite`. If this is not the case, please let me know.*

If you do not want to use a bundled dependency, but instead a global one, then you do the following within a cmd (not Powershell):

```
choco install sqlite
cd C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\SQLite\tools
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"
lib /machine:x64 /def:sqlite3.def /out:sqlite3.lib
```

In order to use `choco` you need to install Chocolately (you can also install Chocolately via Node.js, maybe you already have it installed).

You can get that `.bat` file via the Visual Studio Installer and installing the "Desktop development with C++" Workload.

You can also download the `.def` file from the SQLite website via the 64-bit DLL (x64) for SQLite version 3.42.0 Download instead of using Chocolately, but when using that approach you also need to execute the `.bat` file, you just skip installing a package manager (Chocolately).

Then do the following within Windows Powershell before you execute your `cargo` command.

```
$Env:SQLITE3_LIB_DIR = "<path-to-folder-where-sqlite3-dot-lib-lives>"
```

Then execute your `cargo` command (for example `cargo test`).

Answer (score 1):

i too was stuck.
had to search for many hours.
**i was working on windows platform.**
so here are the steps:

1. download Source Code sqlite-amalgamation file
   and unzip in a folder (e.g. C:\sqlite-dll-win-x64-3440200).
   download link https://www.sqlite.org/download.html
   [image]
2. download Precompiled Binaries for Windows
   and unzip in the above folder (e.g. C:\sqlite-dll-win-x64-3440200).
   [image]
3. press window button and paste "Developer Command Prompt for VS xxx"
   and open that "command shell"
   and go to above folder (e.g. C:\sqlite-dll-win-x64-3440200)
   [image]
4. copy paste this command and press enter
   "lib /DEF:sqlite3.def /OUT:sqlite3.lib /MACHINE:x64"
5. press window button and paste "system environment variables"
   [image]
   search and open "environment variables"
   and go to "system variables" tab
   and search for "path" in the list of variables
   edit it (double click).
   [image]
6. add your folder (e.g. C:\sqlite-dll-win-x64-3440200) under path list and save.

restart the command prompt **(shell)**
**a restart will be best**
and check out the rest

thanks for @Ahmad Rosid for rust tutorial.